# Azure/Provided-hosted Application for on-Premise SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, azure, httpcontext

I would like to make an provided-hosted app for on premise server. I publish this type of application on azure cloud and I've tried to open it in SharePoint on-Premise server and in SharePoint Online. SharePoint Online open this app correctly. Unfortunately SharePoint on-Premise return "401 UNAUTHORIZED" error when it try to connect to azure website. I know that this error is returned, when SharePoint is try to open a website which has "SharePointContextFilter" attribute in controller (It is a MVC SharePoint application). Do you know, how can I open this app on on-premise SharePoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need configure low trust authentication model for on-premise environment.

jansenbe had shared the sample script in github below.

https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-Tools/tree/master/Scripts/SharePoint.LowTrustACS.Configuration

Comment: So it is possible to create a server-side application on an Office 365 tenant and use this application on SharePoint on-premise server? Sorry for my question but I read somewhere that only client-code are allowed.

Comment: You should not use server object model in SharePoint add-in, you could check the thread here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/choose-the-right-api-set-in-sharepoint